# How come Metzudat Tzion never did a perush of difficult words in the chumash?

Tags: historical-figures, pentateuch-chumash, commentaries, acharonim

Why did the author of Metzudat Tzion never write an explanation of difficult words in the chumash, as he did for most of the Nach? There are hard words in the chumash that require explanation even for a fluent Hebrew speaker.

Comment: Welcome, Matthew, to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your question, one I've wondered about also. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: For that matter it was not written on Rus, Eicha, and Esther either. Perhaps he started with Nach and never got to complete it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Metzudat Tzion on the Torah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13491/metzudat-tzion-on-the-torah)

Comment: Thing is I have a copy of מקראות קטנות at home which is like a smaller version of מקראות גדולת at home and does seem to have Metzudat Tzion commentaries for Rus eicha and the Megillah under the name of בית מצודת ציון unless its not actually the commentary of Metzudat Tzion

Comment: @Matthew it's not.

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the [source referenced here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13496/440) he started with Navi due to the poverty of a good collection of Mefarshim, Rashi on Nach is a more advanced pirush that doesn't explain the words the way his Pirush on the Torah does and there was a general lack of expert knowledge on Nach to learn from (I would say that part hasn't improved).

So in other words, he focused on Naviim and Kesuvim because he saw that as in the most need. He never finished with Nach, so going back to doing the same on the Torah never happened, if the author would have found it worthwhile.