# In Psalm 105:39 why is the cloud said to "cover" rather than "precede" the people?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, shemot-exodus

In both Exodus and Nehemiah 9:12 the cloud seems to be a pillar in front of the people but Psalm 105:39 seems to indicate that the cloud traveled above them. Were there two clouds or am I misunderstanding the image?:

> JPS Tanakh 1917 Psalm 105:39 He spread a cloud for a screen; And fire
>   to give light in the night.

I find the idea of a cloud overhead very reasonable but the picture elsewhere seems to be pretty clear that it was a pillar of cloud in front of them:

> JPS Tanakh 1917 Exodus 13:21 And the LORD went **before them** by day
>   **in a pillar of cloud, to lead them the way**; and by night in a pillar of fire, to give them light; that they might go by day and by
>   night:

The account in Numbers 9 seems a bit ambiguous to me:

> 15And on the day that the tabernacle was reared up **the cloud covered
>   the tabernacle**, even the tent of the testimony; and **at even there was
>   upon the tabernacle as it were the appearance of fire**, until morning.
>   16So it was alway: the cloud covered it, and the appearance of fire by
>   night. 17And whenever the cloud was taken up from over the Tent, then
>   after that the children of Israel journeyed; and in the place where
>   the cloud abode, there the children of Israel encamped. 18At the
>   commandment of the LORD the children of Israel journeyed, and at the
>   commandment of the LORD they encamped: as long as the cloud abode upon
>   the tabernacle they remained encamped. 19And when the cloud tarried
>   upon the tabernacle many days, then the children of Israel kept the
>   charge of the LORD, and journeyed not. 20And sometimes the cloud was a
>   few days upon the tabernacle; according to the commandment of the LORD
>   they remained encamped, and according to the commandment of the LORD
>   they journeyed. 21And sometimes the cloud was from evening until
>   morning; and when the cloud was taken up in the morning, they
>   journeyed; or if it continued by day and by night, when the cloud was
>   taken up, they journeyed. 22Whether it were two days, or a month, or a
>   year, that the cloud tarried upon the tabernacle, abiding thereon, the
>   children of Israel remained encamped, and journeyed not; but when it
>   was taken up, they journeyed. 23At the commandment of the LORD they
>   encamped, and at the commandment of the LORD they journeyed; they kept
>   the charge of the LORD, at the commandment of the LORD by the hand of
>   Moses. THE HOLY SCRIPTURES ACCORDING TO THE MASORETIC TEXT A NEW
>   TRANSLATION Jewish Publication Society 1917

I'm having a hard time getting a consistent picture in my mind of what was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to my question:

> JPS Tanakh 1917 Exodus 14: 19And the angel of God, who went before the
> camp of Israel, removed and went behind them; and **the pillar of
> cloud removed from before them, and stood behind them; 20and it came
> between the camp of Egypt and the camp of Israel;** and there was the
> cloud and the darkness here, yet gave it light by night there; and the
> one came not near the other all the night.

So the pillar of cloud interposed between the Israelis and the Egyptians. It wasn't an overhead cloud at all!

I notice two other places where the Lord promises to be a surrounding wall:

> JPS Zechariah 2:9 But I will be for it-says the Lord-a wall of fire around, and for glory I will be in its midst.

> > Rashi: But I will be for it: as a shield, as though a wall of fire surrounds it. Also, My Shechinah shall dwell in its midst for your glory.

> JPS Isaiah 52:12 For not with haste shall you go forth and not in a flurry of flight shall you go, for the Lord goes before you, and your rear guard is the God of Israel.

> > Rashi: for… goes before you: Two things at the end of this verse explain two things in its beginning, [viz.] For not with haste shall you go forth. What is the reason? For the Lord goes before you to lead you on the way, and one whose agent advances before him to lead him on the way his departure is not in haste. And not in the flurry of flight shall you go, for your rear guard is the God of Israel. He will follow you to guard you from any pursuer. Comp. (Num. 10:25) “And the division of the camp of Dan shall travel, the rear guard of all the camps.” Whoever goes after the camp is called מְאַסֵּף, the rear guard, because he waits for the stragglers and the stumblers. Similarly, Scripture states in Joshua (6:13): “And the rear guard was going after the Ark.”

See also:

> JPS Joshua 6:

> 8 And it was when Joshua spoke to the people, and the seven priests bearing the seven trumpets of rams' horns passed on before (the Ark of) the Lord and blew with the trumpets; and the Ark of the covenant of the Lord followed them.
> 9 And the armed men went before the priests that blew the trumpets, and the rear guard came after the Ark, (the priests) going on, and blowing with the trumpets.

> JPS Psalms 5 From the rear and the front You encompassed me, and You placed Your pressure upon me.
>
> > From the rear and the front: My face and my back.
> > Your pressure: your coercion and your ruling, destroit in Old French.

Answer (score 7):

[Rashi to Numbers 10:34](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.10.34?lang=bi):

> Seven times is the word ענן used in the account of their journeys alluding to four clouds which screened them on all four sides, one that was above them, one beneath their feet, and one in front of them which leveled the elevations and raised the depressions, and killed all serpents and scorpions
>
> <sub>*Translation from Sefaria*</sub>

So, according to this understanding, there was indeed one cloud preceding the people, along with six others surrounding or covering them.

[Note that Rashi's sources include the [midrashic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash) texts [Sifrei Bamidbar 83](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Bamidbar.83.1?lang=bi) and [Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 13:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_d'Rabbi_Yishmael.13.21.2?lang=bi), which also quote other opinions as to the number of clouds: thirteen, four or two.]

Answer (score 4):

[*M'tzudas Tziyun* on the spot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.105.39?lang=he&with=Metzudat%20Zion&lang2=he) suggests a way to reconcile both descriptions as the same cloud: it led them when they were moving and covered them when they were stationary. The predictability of this behavior could facilitate picturing it, like fog rolling from one position to another.

> **למסך**. כן יקרא הסכך אשר ממעל גם המחיצה לפנים כמו ואת מסך הפתח (שמות כז) והענן בלכתם הלך לפניהם ובנוחם סככם ממעל

It makes the point that the root ס.כ.כ in the form that it is used here - the noun *masach* - can mean a frontal separator, not just an overhead one. But just when you think that fact will be used to infer that it was never overhead, it returns to the explanation that the cloud had two different placements.

Comment: My issue with this is that when they were stationary the cloud would be upon the tabernacle, per Numbers 9. In fact, it doesn't seem particularly amenable to the 7 cloud theory either.

Comment: I agree that this does not accord with Rash"i in @JoelK's answer, but I think it would be reasonable to fit in the _B'midbar_ cloud with this explanation as well, since the _mishkan_ was within the camp, so what covers one can cover the other. This would require some direct corroboration. Unfortunately, it seems we [do not have](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13496/3) this commentary on the Torah.